# Create a sql query based on selected month from dropdown combobox in excel userform

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have a userform in excel for attendance reporting. On the form the user chooses the employee they want to review, and then they can check a box that says year to date, or select individual months from a combobox drop down. This is all to query our sql server that has the data on it. Year to date is easy, because I know how to use the variables for current date and first day of the year. What I'm having trouble with is how to convert the user's month selection into a usable query. For example: If the user selects January for the drop down, the query would be

```
select * from [dbo.mytablename]
where [agent name] = '<value from a textbox that I know how to pass in>'
and [cal date] > '1/1/2018' and [cal date] < '1/31/2018'
```

Right now my only idea is to have cells on a holding spreadsheet in the workbook that have the first and last day of each month and then use the cell values. But I'd like to avoid that if possible. If you have any ideas that would be great!

Comment: Presuming your months are in order, you can just use the listindex of the dropdown perhaps?  If not, try basing query on `month([cal date])`  another idea is `dateserial()` using the month selected, then monthselected+1 as month -1 day for the last day of month, for example `dateserial(2018,(2+1),1)-1` is the last day in Feb

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your month is a numeric value between 1 and 12, you can use something like

```
Dim fromDate As Date, toDate As Date

fromDate = DateSerial(2018, month, 1)
toDate = DateSerial(2018, month + 1, 1)
Debug.Print fromDate, toDate
```

This will work even with December, `DateSerial` accepts a `13` as month.
Note that you have to ask for *< first day of next month* to catch data from the last day of the month.

Side note: I assume you use a `ADODB.Command` to query the database. I would strongly suggest that you use `ADODB.parameter` to pass the dates (and the agent name) to the database - you don't have to deal with formatting or converting the dates so that the database understand them correctly. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10353908/edit to get an idea how this works.

**Update**
I assume you fill your combo box with values from a range and the value is linked to a cell. Use for example the `match` function to get the month as number (I would never trust that the name of a month is translated correctly by Excel or the database, there are too many things like regional settings that could cause that it breaks). 
Assuming:
Range with month names: A1..A12
Linked cell: B1
Put the formula `=MATCH(B1,A1:A12)` in cell B2. Voilà, you have the number of the month.

Comment: The months are listed as January, February etc. I thought about just using 1-12 but the goal is ease of use for our executives. The parameter idea is great though. I'll definitely incorporate that.

Comment: Then you need a function to convert the names to numbers. See my update for a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
and [cal date] > '1/1/2018' and [cal date] < '1/31/2018'
```

will select all data from Jan 1 to Jan 30 and not include any data from Jan 31.

Keeping this in mind, the check should be

```
and [cal date] > '1/1/2018' and [cal date] < '2/1/2018'
```

So if you do get a month from drop down you can do something like below

```
select * from [dbo.mytablename] t
join
(values 
('Jan', 1),('Feb',2),('Mar', 3),
('Apr', 4),('May',5),('Jun', 6),
('Jul', 7),('Aug',8),('Sep', 9),
('Oct', 10),('Nov',11),('Dec', 12)
)v(mon,num)
on v.mon='<month name received from a text box>'
t.[agent name] = '<value from a textbox that I know how to pass in>'
and t.[cal date] > cast(cast(v.num as varchar)+'/1/2018'  as date)
and t.[cal date] < cast(cast((v.num+1)%12 as varchar)+'/1/'+ cast(2018+ (v.num/12) as varchar) as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server there are numerous techniques for date calculation/converions.  If 2012+ you can use `EOMonth()` or `DateFromParts()`.

I should also add `[cal date] < '1/31/2018'` should be `[cal date] <= '1/31/2018'`

**Example**

```
Select StrCast1   = try_convert(date,concat('January',' 1, ',2018))
      ,StrCast2   = EOMonth(try_convert(date,concat('January',' 1, ',2018)))
      ,FromParts1 = DateFromParts(2018,1,1)
      ,FromParts2 = EOMonth(DateFromParts(2018,1,1))
```

**Returns**

```
StrCast1    StrCast2    FromParts1  FromParts2
2018-01-01  2018-01-31  2018-01-01  2018-01-31
```